# OnActivityResult only called when cancel

Tags: android, camera

I have an activity that starts an intent with startActivityForResult

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);

takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,getFilesDir());
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

And in the same class, the onActivityResult :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    }
    else
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

The class extends AppCompatActivity. 
onActivityResult is only triggered when I cancel the intent (when back button is pressed). Nothing happens when a picture is taken.

Has anyone an solution ?

---

I'm aware that this is a duplicate of 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions

but according to [How to re-ask an old question which is not answered yet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272468/how-to-re-ask-an-old-question-which-is-not-answered-yet) , I could only edit the question (which I'm apparently not allowed to do) and I don't have enough bounty to place it, so I could only ask the question again ..

Comment: is getFilesDir() overwritten? You should pass a uri to a file, to which your app can write. Otherwise the camera cannot store the image. Why don't you debug your code and check if onActivityResult is really not called, or if none of your if else conditions captures the result. Also check LogCat for warnings.

Comment: I debugged the app in android studio by placing breakpoints at the beginning of the method, and it clearly showed me that it only triggers when the camera is cancelled. I'll give a try for the uri and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs:

First, `EXTRA_OUTPUT` needs to point to a *file*, not a *directory*.

Second, you are then ignoring `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, expecting a picture to come back via the `"data"` extra.

I suggest you start by commenting out your `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,getFilesDir());` line. At this point, there are two possibilities:

1. Things start working. In that case, what happened was that your invalid `EXTRA_OUTPUT` value was causing the user's chosen camera app to fail.
2. You still do not get control in `onActivityResult()` when the user takes a picture. In this case, the camera app is buggy, most likely, and there is little that you can do about that.

Comment: I commented the line, the behavior stayed exactly the same, nothing happened when taking the picture, but the onActivityResult is triggered when cancelling. Alternatively, I changed `getFilesDir()` to `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,file)` with `File file = new File("picture");` but that didn't work either

Comment: @ArthurAttout: `new File("picture")` does not point anywhere. `new File(getFilesDir(), "picture")` would be valid (assuming `picture` does not already exist as a directory). But if the camera app is ignoring you even when you do not supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, then the camera app has bugs. [That is all too common](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html).

Comment: Ok so that would mean that it is impossible to take a picture within the app ? Although, some apps already have that implemented so that must be something with my code. Otherwise I'll have to tell the project manager that this functionality won't be on the app, which clearly isn't an option for me at this point.

Comment: @ArthurAttout: "so that would mean that it is impossible to take a picture within the app ?" -- you are welcome to use the camera APIs directly. "some apps already have that implemented so that must be something with my code" -- if they are running on this device, either they are using the camera APIs directly, or perhaps they are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and the camera app bug that you are experiencing is limited to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE`.

Comment: @ArthurAttout: By using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`/`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE`, you are explicitly delegating the picture-taking work to a third-party app. There are literally hundreds of these, between pre-installed camera apps and ones users download. Ideally, you would get consistent results with all of them. Ideally, I would have hair.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri=Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

and in your ActivityResult

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                    options);
    }

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/yourFolderName/");

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(dir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        System.out.println("Media FIle is:--" + mediaFile);
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot resolve getOutputMediaFile, is it in Activity ?

Comment: ohh sorry...it is a method i forgot to add...check my edit

Comment: Unfortunately this code is not working with me, I get a nullPointerException. I think I'll give up the intent and start working with the camera API, which seems to be an gigantic pile of awful code, but that's the way it is

Comment: Where do you get nullPointerExecption?

Comment: The exception is a bit unclear `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.standard.appsupporter.debug/be.standard.appsupporter.features.pix.PixCameraActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: file`

Comment: Have you added the permission of  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your menifest? and if you are running on android 6 then you have to provide run time permission

Comment: Yes, everything is done as you said .. Thanks for the help anyways, I'll go for the huge pile of code, at least that's something Andriod hasn't done at half

Comment: Well...All the best